# Is the following HTML comment necessary?

Tags: discussion, support, syntax-highlighting

My post is being edited by the same user on different posts and the only change is following line of code is being added at the top of the edited post:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-js -->
```

I think my post already has formatting syntax. But I can see there's the edit summary stating "applied syntax meta".

---

I cannot reject the edit due to the user's reputation. And doing a rollback is ugly if this happens all the time.

So, I wanted to know if this is necessary?

Here's an [example post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52574020/2138752). You may see the change by clicking on the "edit" link button.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This edit added syntax highlighting to the code blocks. (This makes different parts of the code change color based on its function: upper case words are one color, numbers another, and keywords a different color still.)

There was no syntax highlighting there originally because [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) (i.e. what the question is tagged as) doesn't have a language for highlighting associated with it. In contrast, [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) at the very bottom of its tag wiki says:

> Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): default

"Default" means that it guesses what language it is, which works well for JavaScript questions because they often contain both JavaScript and HTML. When you use `lang-js` for HTML (as was done with the edit) it doesn't really look right.

Thus, the right action would have been to not edit the answer at all and instead add [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) to the question, which will:

- Add syntax highlighting to the current answer and all future answers. If the question is edited later to add code this too will have syntax highlighting.
- Properly highlight HTML.
- Classify the question a little better. React is after all a JavaScript library.

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused. If there's no javascript tag, then I should add that comment?

Comment: @Bhojendra Rauniyar: If there's no language tag, look at the question and determine if a language tag is appropriate, and add one if so. Tagging the question correctly should be a priority over adding language hints - the latter is meant to work around limitations with the former (e.g. two or more language tags that apply to the question but have conflicting non-default language hints).

Answer (score 4):

That comment is adding JavaScript [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) to the code blocks. If you have another look at [the revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52574020/revisions), you will notice they had no highlighting in the original revision. As the only tag of the post is [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs), which has no highlighting associated to it (otherwise it would be mentioned at the very end of [its tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reactjs/info)), the edit is appropriate.

Comment: Yes, but it is leaving all other problems untouched. E.g, the awkward first sentence, missing article before "title", misspelling of [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)), strange comma after "Where", and the partly incomprehensible last sentence (what does *"following `App` component"* mean? Missing definite article? - though it would still be awkward and perhaps not the actual intent). OK, the last item is probably a candidate for a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: And the ***syntax highlighting is incorrect*** for the first part: `<div id="root"></div>` should get syntax highlighted as HTML, not JavaScript. It may not have looked weird then, but it definitely does now (the new weird syntax highlighter was [introduced in September 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter).). For example, the HTML start and end tags should be orange-ish. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73668084).